# github actions - cannot connect to mysql

Tags: docker, github, mariadb, github-actions

so I am trying to setup a laravel ci server with github actions. And, i am using `edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php:7.3` as my container, and I use the official mariadb docker as mysql service.:

```
services:
      mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.3
        env:
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
          - 13306:3306 
...
```

and I am trying to run, run mysql command to import db:

```
  - name: Setting Up DB
        run: |
          mysql -Tv -h mysql -P 13306 --protocol=tcp -u root -proot < ./storage/test.sql
```

And here are the several attempts I did:

```
| host               | error message                                                          |
|--------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| mysql,"${DB_HOST}" | ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)             |
| 0.0.0.0            | ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (115)   |
| 127.0.0.1          | ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115) |
| (without host)     | ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)  |
```

Not sure what else I can do here ...

here is what I also tried, all tells me that **option don't exist**:

```
 services:
      mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.3
        options: --bind_address=""
        env:
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
          - 13306:3306
```

and I tried with options :

1. `--disable_bind_address`
2. `--bind-address=""`

Here are some log messages I got from github: (-Tv did not give anything useful)

```
docker.io/library/mariadb:10.3
/usr/bin/docker create --name 607ae471e5844570b9e2fcf4f57ed78a_mariadb103_d94369 --label 2b5be7 --workdir /__w/laravel/laravel --network github_network_ab8a7ba8c1624f95bdc2784147b4b5e1 --network-alias mysql -p 13306:3306 -e "MYSQL_USER=root" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" -e "HOME=/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work":"/__w" -v "/home/runner/runners/2.157.3/externals":"/__e":ro -v "/home/runner/work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/home/runner/work/_actions":"/__w/_actions" -v "/opt/hostedtoolcache":"/__t" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" mariadb:10.3
 c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3
/usr/bin/docker start c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3
c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3
/usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3 --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3 Up Less than a second
/usr/bin/docker port c3b10a5c4799a671f55c2f2b7a33803abd9228830be5e8821b51f10a2b2951b3
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:13306
```

Comment: from where you run the import script? is it in same docker-compose?

Comment: it is github actions, so in `steps`

Comment: github action running inside docker or same docker-compose file?

Comment: docker, I don't think they use docker compose

Comment: ` mysql -Tv -h mysql -P 13306 ` here `-h mysql` host is only accesible in container if it launch in same docker compose

Comment: then how does github actions know where mysql is ... such a mystery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198964/discussion-between-adiii-and-shuyi).

Comment: Well, what _telnet 0.0.0.0 13306_ returns from **where github actions is executed**? Other thing, I saw that you have tried bind_address, but how? Have you seen [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)?

Comment: I have a similar problem using Django. I think it's in the host name or the user needs '%' permission for remote access to the database. I'm doing tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe try like this :

```
 mysql: 
    image: mariadb:10.3 
    env:    
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root   
    ports:  
    - 3306:3306 
    options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
```

There is a healthcheck to be sure the service is healthy before connexion